# Strange output of a SetTimeout() function

Tags: javascript, html, closures, settimeout

I came accross following question and I simply cannot understand it, how it got the output. Can someone explain?

```html
<html>
<head></head>
<body>

<script>
const arr = [10, 12, 15, 21];
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  setTimeout(function() {
console.log('Index: ' + i + ', element: ' + arr[i]);
  }, 3000);
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

**Expected:**

```
Index: 0, element: 10
Index: 1, element: 12
Index: 2, element: 15
Index: 3, element: 21
```

**Output:**

```
Index: 4, element: undefined (4 times)
```

It doesn't make any sense, how this is the output.

Comment: You can refer to the following link for more details. https://medium.com/coderbyte/a-tricky-javascript-interview-question-asked-by-google-and-amazon-48d212890703

Comment: It cannot be explained. Not the output you get. However, if the output is four lines of `Index: 4, element: undefined` then it makes perfect sense. The `console.log()` is executed long after the for loop has ended. At that stage the value of `i` is 4 and `arr[4]` is undefined.

Comment: const arr = [10, 12, 15, 21];
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  setTimeout(function(i) {
console.log('Index: ' + i + ', element: ' + arr[i]);
  }(i), 3000);
}

use this